# Dynamic query in a for loop

Tags: apex, soql, governorlimits, dynamic-soql

I need to retrieve the CreatedDate of the last record creates of every custom object. But the only way I find to do it is by doing a dynamic query in a For or loop. But I’m, of course, limited to 100 custom objects. Did anyone have a solution to avoid the query in the loop ? 
Or any other workaround  ? Thanks

I give you a sample of my code :

```
public void  method() {
    List<ObjectBuilder__c> listOfRecord = new List<ObjectBuilder__c> () ;       
    for(Schema.SObjectType objTyp : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values())
    {
        ObjectBuilder__c oneRecord = new ObjectBuilder__c ()  ; 
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult describeSObjectResultObj = objTyp.getDescribe();
        objectName = objTyp.getDescribe().getLabel() ; 

        if(describeSObjectResultObj.isCustom() ) {
            if(!name.containsignorecase('history') && !name.containsignorecase('tag')&&
             !name.containsignorecase('share') && !name.containsignorecase('feed') ) {
                oneRecord.Api_Name__c = objTyp.getDescribe().getName(); ; 
                List<sObject> tmp = Database.query('SELECT CreatedDate  FROM '+ oneRecord.Api_Name__c +' order by CreatedDate  desc limit 1 ');
                System.debug('tmp list '+tmp);
                for(sObject obj :tmp ) {
                    oneRecord.Last_Used_Date__c =Date.valueOf(obj.get('CreatedDate')) ; 
                    listOfRecord.add(oneRecord) ;              
                }                      
             }
        }

    }

    INSERT listOfRecord ;

} `
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to store the last time a record was created in every custom object. With that information I can make a report and know which object is used or not for the last 3/6/9/12 months..

Answer (score 6):

Each type of record does have to be queried separately so using a batchable to break up the work into less than 100 types per transaction is how I would approach this:

```
public class MyBatchable implements Database.Batchable<String> {

    public static void executeAsync() {
        Database.executeBatch(new MyBatchable(), 50);
    }

    public  String[] start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        // Return all the types (hundreds)
        String[] types = ...;
        return types;
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, String[] scope) {
        ObjectBuilder__c[] records = new ObjectBuilder__c[] {};
        // Query the scope types (less than 100)
        insert records;
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    }
}
```

then:

```
MyBatchable.executeAsync();
```

Comment: Ha. Great minds, I guess. Asynchronous query limit is 200, though. Might as well use the greatest available value.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yep good point.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a batch to get this sort of information. Something like:

```
public class DemoBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObjectType>
{
    public List<SObjectType> start(Database.BatchableContext context)
    {
        return Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values();
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<SObjectType> types)
    {
        List<MyObject__c> records = new List<MyObject__c>();
        for (SObjectType type : types)
        {
            Datetime createdDate = getMostRecentCreatedDate(type);
            if (createdDate != null) records.add(new MyObject__c(
                Api_Name__c = String.valueOf(type),
                Last_Created_Date__c = createdDate
            ));
        }
        insert records;
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) { }

    public static Datetime getMostRecentCreatedDate(SObjectType type)
    {
        try
        {
            List<SObject> records = Database.query(
                'SELECT CreatedDate FROM ' + type + ' ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1'
            );
            return records.isEmpty() ? null : (Datetime)records[0].get('CreatedDate');
        }
        catch (QueryException q) { return null; }
    }
}
```

Then execute it with a batch size that will not exceed your governor limits:

```
Database.execute(new DemoBatch()); // limit is 200 in the asynchronous context
```